# Listview selectedItem

Tags: c#, list, listview

How do I use the `ListView`'s `ItemSelectionChanged` event? I have a `ListView`, which in turn has 8 columns; and the first column of each row contains the Id for the row and this is what I'm after.

I need this because the Id is to be used to select info from a list. This list is what populates the `ListView`, but it doesn't show all of the info. The info not being shown is to be displayed in a `RichTextBox` and, of course, it should display the info for that selected item in the `ListView`. The Id's are the same, of course, but no matter what I try I can't seem to reach that value.

My code so far:

```
foreach ([ClassName] x in [List])
{
    if (x.id == Convert.ToInt32(myListView.FocusedItem.Text))
    {
        rtbxSpecific.Text = x.name;
    }
}
```

This works great for the first object in the `ListView`, but not for any of the following where it throws a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx). Why does this happen? It's like the event fires, but it doesn't know about any other item in the list except for the first one.

I've also tried using `selectedItems[0].Text`, `selectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text` but it's basically the same fault. This is really annoying me and I would be really thankful if someone could explain why it works for the first `ListViewItem`, but not the following.

I even tried using `Find(...)` on the list with:

```
[Class] cl = [List].Find(delegate([Class] q) {return q.id == Convert.ToInt32(myListView.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text);});
```

But no dice, which leads me to believe its the `FocusedItem` that is being nasty right now and I'm not getting anywhere with this. The `Find(...)` method would be cleaner to use, I suppose, but right now I'm getting the same error with both.

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger around the place you get the `NullReferenceException` to see *what* is `null`?

Comment: MSDN is your friend... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx

Comment: How are the items added to your listview, are they object's of a custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple check to see if the selected item.count was > 0.

```
if (myListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    foreach ([Class] cl in [List])
    {
        if (myListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text == cl.[Field].ToString())
        {
            RichTextBox.Text = cl.[Field];
        }
    }
}
```